# Python, Make one string with elements adding comas between them

Tags: string, concatenation, element

I want to make one string with comas betweewn elemets like this:

In:

```html
['ElementA','ElementB','ElementC']
```

Out:

```html
['ElementA,ElementB,ElementC']
```

Thank you

Comment: the below python solution did not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript solution:

```js
let arr = ['ElementA','ElementB','ElementC'] ;

let arr2 = [arr.join(",")];

console.log(arr2);
```

Python solution:

```
arr = ['ElementA','ElementB','ElementC']
separator = ','
arr2 = [separator.join(arr)]
print(arr2)
```